# Whose responsibility is it to advise impact to transit time due to flight changes by partner airline(s)

Tags: transit, airlines, layovers, code-share

Transiting from Dubai via Madrid to a local flight in Spain operated by Iberia. (Terminal 4S arrival, Terminal 4). All tickets issued by Emirates. Original transit time 2.5 hours, now down to 25 minutes. Iberia have advised me of the the flight change as a FYI (but have not mentioned the transit time might be an issue etc). I've heard nothing from Emirates although I can now see my itinerary has changes. Is it always upon the traveler to work out that there might be an issue (25 minutes is to short to transfer from 4S to 4 in Madrid) after changes in connecting flights (even if they are on a single ticket)?

Comment: Every airport publishes minimum transit time and 25 min will be too small of a transit time as per any airport. From what I know, airlines try to adhere to these published minimum transit times when they issue a hopping ticket. However, they aren’t regulated by anyone and the onus of being able to connect is almost always on the passenger. But I would wait for other opinions too.

Comment: Yes Madrid airport has a minimum transit time of >1 hour from what I've read for transfer from International to EU zone flights (Which is terminal 4S to 4 in Madrid). You would think it would be simple batch program for an airline to run nightly looking for violations that have arisen due to changes in flights. They enforce it when booking a ticket, should be ongoing housekeeping

Answer (score 6):

For a schedule change in advance it is always the ticketing carrier (in this case, Emirates) that is responsible for rebooking you after the change.

In a perfect world this would be handled automatically, but when multiple airlines are involved it generally doesn't - especially when those airlines are not part of the same alliance (Emirates is NOT OneWorld, despite your questions heading).  I would suggest reaching out to whoever you purchased your ticket from (either Emirates or the travel agent) and asking them to arrange an alternative. It is possible they will contact you, but the earlier you arrange the alternative the better the options may be.

Depending on how much notice you were given of this change and how much you need to change your arrival time, you may be able to claim compensation under [EU261](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004).

Comment: Compensation under EU261 is not obvious, given it’s a trip To the EU rather than from the EU, and the carrier probably being non-EU. I’m not sure what the precedents are (if any) for a mixed-flight in that direction.

Comment: @jcaron Iberia rescheduled the flight, and are an EU carrier. Whilst the ticketing carrier is responsible for rebooking the passenger, the carrier that rescheduled the flight would be responsible for the compensation.

Comment: @Doc thanks I've updated the question to remove the statement that Emirates is part of OneWorld. Ticket purchased direct with Emirates BTW